# How to keep matplotlib plots alive after process ends

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Comrades,

I have a function that should generate some matplotlib plots and then terminate.  I want the plots to remain after it terminates.

- If I set interactive mode on, the plot appears, does not block, and then disappears when my function terminates.  I don't want this.
- If I set interactive mode off, the plot appears, then blocks until you close it, and then the function terminates.  I don't want this either.

Desired behaviour is: The plot appears, does not block, and remains after the function terminates.

So people, is there a way to do this?  The most likely approach seems to be multiprocessing.  I would have thought the following code would work:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_graph():
    plt.plot(np.random.randn(10))
    plt.show()

p = Process(target=plot_graph)
p.start()
```

But it does not show anything (at least on MacOS, backend TkAgg)

I know I can just save the figure as an image and open the image, but this is not quite what I want - I'd like to still be able to use the matplotlib zoom controls, etc.

Comment: Try moving `plt.show()` after `p.start()`?

Comment: What do you mean?  show is called after start, in the new process.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but yours is behaving as if show() is not blocking. Try adding plt.ioff() as in the below.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_graph():
    plt.plot(np.random.randn(10))
    plt.show()

plt.ioff()
p = Process(target=plot_graph)
p.start()
```

Comment: Yes, but it works without the pause also. If your program is terminating (it should block on the show command), try adding plt.ioff() before setting p = ... I modified my original answer above

Comment: Hmmm.. thanks, but no dice.  If it works for you and not for me it must be some kind of plotting backend issue.